# Overriding python builtin 'print' using pybing11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm embedding Python into a C++ app using pybind11. I'm trying to override the Python builtin 'print' function from C++.

```
mBuiltinsMod = py::module::import("builtins");
mBuiltinsMod.attr("print") = py::cpp_function([](py::object msg) {
    std::cout << msg.cast<std::string>();
});
```

This successfully overrides the 'print' function to call cout, but it crashes on program exit. The crash happes on `pybind11/embed.h`:

```
void finalize_interpreter() {
    // ...
    if (internals_ptr_ptr) { // CRASH HERE
        delete *internals_ptr_ptr;
        *internals_ptr_ptr = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Are there other steps needed when overriding the 'print' function to fix the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

First, lock the GIL. Then, assign none() to print:

```
mBuiltinsMod.attr("print") = py::none();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

void my_print(py::args args) {
    // Concatenate the input arguments into a single string
    std::stringstream ss;
    ((ss << py::str(arg) << " "), ...);

    // Output the concatenated string to the Python console
    py::print(ss.str());
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("print", &my_print);
}
```